# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using TrueTypeFontFactory in Libgdx for android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been trying to run a libgdx Android project but it just wont work out in any way. It's showing:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5502): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.stbtt.TrueTypeFontFactory

I have used gdx-stb-truetype.jar library of libgdx extension to show TTF Fonts.
My project structure is this:

```
Common project:
included gdx-stb-truetype.jar and gdx-stb-truetype-natives.jar as reference library

Android Project:
Referenced Project: Common project

Desktop Project:
Referenced Project: Common project
```

It's running great on desktop project but can't run it on Android.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9833655/420015)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like TrueTypeFontFactory is deprecated in libGDX.