# Add view class defined in external lbrary project

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a new GLView component to be aded to different projects. After building the library correctly I am trying to add it to a xml layout in my test app, but it doesn't seem to work as it throws a classnotfound exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:lib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<com.exapmple.library.CustomView
android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the class inside the external project is:

```
public class CustomView extends GLSurfaceView
```

Comment: May be this answer helps?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833607/android-eclipse-noclassdeffounderror-for-external-jar-files

Comment: The library is there and can be called from anywhere in the code. The layout xml files are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How do you attach your library to the project?

As jar lib or as Library project?

I suppose the problem is in wrong configuration. May be jar file placed in "lib" folder instead of "libs".

Comment: Library project. It can be called from anywhere in the code so it has been correctly imported. The XML files need the lib's namespace definition.