# android NoClassDefFound error

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new to coding in android and I ran into a problem today. I was able to run this a couple of hours ago but suddenly it just started giving me a NoClassDefFound error. Please help me find out why it suddenly started giving me errors.

Logcat:

```
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850): Process: com.Blocks.blocks, PID: 31850
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.Blocks.blocks.Play
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at com.Blocks.blocks.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
11-16 22:44:34.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31850):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my MainActivity.java (All imports are included)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button play,Exits,AboutMe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("12A7F007F53439A00E30C06216544A0B").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Play);
        Exits=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Exit);
        AboutMe=(Button)findViewById(R.id.AboutMe);
        final Context context = this;

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intents=new Intent(context,Play.class);
                startActivity(intents);
            }
        });
        Exits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        AboutMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(context,AboutMe.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Line 35 is this:

```
Intent intents=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Play.class);
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Blocks.blocks"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"
    />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".AboutMe"
            android:label="@string/AboutT" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:name=".Play"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/Play" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I have the same problem with you and I see the same pattern that you and I have. The cause seems to be screenOrientation, I know because I hit on the NoClassDefFound error after I force my screenOrientation to landscape and I haven’t found any solution yet..

Answer (score 1):

Clean Project after try it working fine.

Comment: You mean clean project? If you mean clean project, I have already done that and it does not work.

Comment: i face to same problem my android studio project. clean project after working fine my side.

Comment: Please refer this link very usefull  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833607/android-eclipse-noclassdeffounderror-for-external-jar-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutMe.class);
```

instead Of

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,AboutMe.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it gives me the same error ):

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
Intent intents=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Play.class);
```

**UPDATE**

It seems because you have 2 `Play` : One is an instance of `Button` and one is `Activity`. Change the instance of `button` to play (**lowercase** p) and this code should work.

Comment: I've tried that but it gave me the same error message as before.

Answer (score 0):

Activity context available in activity methods only,so instead of setting context in activity class set it in `onCreate` method as

```
context = this;
```

and declare in your activity as `Context context;` instead of `final Context context = this;`
i.e. rewrite your code as

```
 Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;  // add here
```

or change

```
Intent intents=new Intent(context,Play.class);
```

to

```
Intent intents=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Play.class);
```

Comment: I've done both of those, the first one forces me to change it to final or else context does not work. The second one gives me same error code as before. Thanks for replying so fast though.

Comment: @AndrewChan then change  `Context context;` to `final Context context;` and clear your project and retry.And also post manifest file.

Comment: I've done that as well haha. Crashes and gives me the error again.

Answer (score 0):

`Play` is a variable of type `Button` in your code above.  Do you have an activity named `Play` defined in Play.class somewhere?  If so, the `Play` variable is interfering with seeing it.  Usually, Java coding styles says that class name start with capital letter and variable names start with a lower case letter.  `Play.class` looks like a static reference, but it is really just a regular reference to a `Button`.

My guess is you mention to reference a different activity.  If you have `Play.class` with a Play `Activity`, rename `Play` to `play` (change all of references except the problem line)

Comment: Do you have a class called Play.java somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I can post it. However I will warn you that it is EXTREMELY ugly...by ugly I mean that I got very lazy and put all my code into that one file haha.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue few times, it can easily be removed by cleaning the project and than reinstalling it, what Blaze Tama showed is quite preferable way of writing intents to change activity if you choose not to write getApplicationContext();

Comment: How exactly do I reinstall the project? And yeah, I could see that way being better.

Comment: well ctrl+F11 does the same thing, Did cleaning the project help you with your issues?

Comment: did you make any changes to Play activity in anyway that you see could give you an error?

Comment: Not that I recall. I didn't touch it after I published my app on the market. It worked perfectly at the time.

Comment: well did you add AddMob in you app and it stooped working, is that the case?

Comment: Admob was included in my app that was published and it functioned correctly at the time.

Comment: kindly forward your link to your app, I will see what I can do?

Comment: [link]https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Blocks.blocks&hl=en[/link]
It's my first app so it's not much :) but thanks for taking your time to figure this out for me.

Comment: don't worry, You did well for your first app, keep it up, I will get back to you with possible solution if I could find a one