# Android Eclipse NoClassDefFoundError for external .jar android files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am facing `Error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when importing a `jar` and using its classes.

This problem might be thought of a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833607/android-eclipse-noclassdeffounderror-for-external-jar-files) question. But I have  a different condition:

I have prepared a `.jar` file from `Eclipse SDK for Android` .so it has folder such as `/res /assets` etc.

I have goggled for solution tried some of the solutions:

> - Build path-> Configure BuildPath->Add External jar
> - Copy .jar to /libs directory.

None of them worked!!!

**P.S.** In a previous project i have already used `SQLCipher.jar` file by just by adding it to the build path and have faced no problems.Though It had some `filename.dat` (which i have to add into /assets folder) and i have no idea what so ever if that has any role in accessing  methods in the class of the jar.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using Android Studio, the gradle build system is much easier than adding the libs manually. Just add compile 'net.sqlcipher:sqlcipher-gradle:3.0.1' to the build script, and the library will be downloaded and added with 1 mouse click.

Eclipse is missing powerfull features that Android Studio has

On toppic:
You need to import the jars from the build config dialog, click import external jar and select your jar

Comment: Thanks for your sugesstion on Android Studio. try  to work on that. But about importing external jars ; I have threid the method sugessted by you. And still getting run time error

Comment: @SidharthDash Have you checked the export checkbox for your lib in the dialog? I don't know which one it was, but you need to select the library for export. Then it will be exported

Answer (score 0):

The library you added may need some external library eg google play services or something, do check that